# Mutt - Automatic Display Sent Email

Tags: email, mutt

I using Mutt and I am trying to replicate Gmail's behaviour after sending an e-mail. It stays on the thread of the conversation and shows the sent e-mail. After sending a message in the Mutt interface (compose or reply), how can I display the sent message automatically (after pressing send, go automatically to "read" the sent message, without shortcuts)?

Answer (score 0):

if you set 'record' to point to the same directory as your 'spoolfile' you should be able to achieve what you want. In other words both point to your 'Inbox' where you receive new mail.
All the best.

Comment: thank you for the reply, but my aim is to avoid selecting the message and pressing enter (also placing sent emails into the inbox).